# getting the error "ERROR: EOF" when i execute a Heroku command "heroku login" in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, heroku

I installed the heroku on my ubuntu sytem, in order to deploy my app to heroku through heroku cli. but when i run `heroku login` i am getting the following error.

```
    prashant@prashant-pc:~$ heroku login
    ERROR: EOF
    !    error getting commands pid 4387 exit 1
    prashant@prashant-pc:~$
```

i istalled the heroku client using the following command

```
   sudo wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

what is the issue? can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

First: remove .heroku

```
rm -r /home/<user>/.heroku
```

Second: update heroku

```
heroku update
```

Comment: It will help others understand better, if you explain why this situation happens and how your solution solves it.