# heroku version giving the error, "ERROR: EOF" while executing the command "heroku version" in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04, heroku-toolbelt

i installed heroku toolbelt in my ubuntu 14.04 operating system, using the following command.

```
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

and seams it got installed in my system. after that when i type heroku version i am getting the error.

```
prashant@prashant-pc:~$ heroku version
ERROR: EOF
!    error getting commands pid 18296 exit 1
prashant@prashant-pc:~$ heroku login
ERROR: EOF
!    error getting commands pid 18440 exit 1
prashant@prashant-pc:~$
```

can anyone help me on this?

here is the terminal output when i executed the installation command,

`wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

```
prashant@prashant-pc:~$ wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
--2015-12-12 15:35:45--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)... 75.101.151.245, 107.20.142.220, 184.72.95.196
Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)|75.101.151.245|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 719 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

100%[=====================================================================================================>] 719         --.-K/s   in 0s      

This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
2015-12-12 15:35:47 (96.5 MB/s) - written to stdout [719/719]

You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
[sudo] password for prashant: 
--2015-12-12 15:35:52--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)... 107.20.142.220, 184.72.95.196, 75.101.151.245
Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)|107.20.142.220|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1737 (1.7K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

100%[=====================================================================================================>] 1,737       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-12-12 15:35:53 (102 MB/s) - written to stdout [1737/1737]

OK
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                                                                                      
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                                                                             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                                                                                   
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                                                                                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                                                                                             
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [64.4 kB]                                                                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                                                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                                                                                   
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                                                                                           
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                                                                                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources                                                                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                                                                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                                                                                           
Get:2 http://downloads.hipchat.com stable InRelease [2,093 B]                                                                                 
Ign http://downloads.hipchat.com stable InRelease                                                                                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                                                                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                                                                                              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                                                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources                                                                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                                                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages                                                                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                                                                                        
Ign http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                                                                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                                                                                 
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages                                                                        
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [247 kB]                                                                       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                                                                                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                                                                                        
Ign http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                                                                                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages                                                                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages                                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages                                                                 
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg                                                                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages                                                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en                                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en                                                                      
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,359 B]                                                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en                                                                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                                                                                    
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release                                                                                     
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [145 kB]                                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en                                                                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages                                                                                            
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5,167 B]                                                                
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [665 kB]                                                                
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_IN                                                                                           
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]                                                         
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [332 kB]                                                            
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en                                                                                              
Hit http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main amd64 Packages                                                                                   
Hit http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main i386 Packages                                                                                    
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]                                                        
Ign http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                                                                                
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [644 kB]                                                                
Ign http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main Translation-en                                                                                   
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]                                                         
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [334 kB]                                                            
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.2 kB]                                                         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en                                                                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en                                                                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en                                                                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                                                                                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources                                                                          
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources                                                                            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources                                                                          
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                                         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages                                                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages                                                                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages                                                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages                                                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                                                                                        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en                                                                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                                                                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en                                                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                                                                                        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en                                                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                                                                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                                                                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                                                                                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                                                                                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                                                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                                                                                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                                                                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                                                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                                                                                        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                                                                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                                                                                        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                                                                                    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                                                                              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                                                                                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                                                                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IN                                                                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                                                                             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                                                                               
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                                                                                
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN                                                                          
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN                                                                          
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN                                                                            
Fetched 2,501 kB in 22s (110 kB/s)                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://downloads.hipchat.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AAD4AA21729B5780
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  heroku-toolbelt
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 699 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/662 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package heroku-toolbelt.
(Reading database ... 184371 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../heroku-toolbelt_3.42.25_all.deb ...
Unpacking heroku-toolbelt (3.42.25) ...
Setting up heroku-toolbelt (3.42.25) ...
prashant@prashant-pc:~$
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It was working fine yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I found previous answer to this question:
[getting the error "ERROR: EOF" when i execute a Heroku command "heroku login" in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118558/getting-the-error-error-eof-when-i-execute-a-heroku-command-heroku-login-in)

First: remove .heroku

```
rm -r /home/<user>/.heroku
```

Second: update heroku

```
heroku update
```